# Bootstrap model window for ajax load PHP

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, simplemodal

https://gist.github.com/drewjoh/1688900
I downloaded this code and it works really great for me with a warning.

My html code looks like this.

```
      <a href="pop1.php?id=<?php echo $row['book_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $row['book_name']; ?></a>
```

I was able to see a model window but while clicking I'm getting the below error

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: pop1.php?id=1
```

I have checked with stackoverflow answers but nothing helps me.

Could someone help me out.

Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple.

Here is how to fix the issue.

Old HTML code:

```
<a href="pop1.php?id=<?php echo $row['book_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $row['book_name']; ?></a>
```

New HTML Code:

```
<a data-target="#" href="pop1.php?id=<?php echo $row['book_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $row['book_name']; ?></a>
```

Just we need to add the data-target to #

Hope this will help someone.

Thanks again
Kimz